Computability of Singular Expansion of Inverse Function by Lagrange Inversion
Background
A wide variety of recursive structures from enumerative combinatorics (e.g., trees) satisfy an equation of the form $y=z\phi(y)$, where $\phi$ is a nonlinear function with $\phi(0)\neq 0$ and $[x^n]\phi(x)\geq 0$, and it is the (asymptotic expansion of the) coefficients of $y(z)$ that are of interest. Obtaining an expansion of $y=z\phi(y)$ in $z$ amounts to implicitly representing $y$ as a function of $z$ around a point $(z,y)=(\rho,\tau)$, where, $\tau$ fulfills $\phi(\tau)-\tau\phi'(\tau)=0$ and,
$$
\rho=\frac{\tau}{\phi(\tau)}.
$$
Question
On pages 406-7 of Analytic Combinatorics (Flagolet & Sedgewick, 2009), the note VI.15. Computability of Singular Expansion defines the following function,
$$
h(w) := \sqrt{\frac{\frac{\tau}{\phi(\tau)} - \frac{w}{\phi(w)}}{(\tau - w)^2}}.
$$
The note continues by stating that since $h$ fulfills $\sqrt{\rho-z}=(\tau-y)h(y)$, one can obtain the singular expansion of $y(z)$ in $z$ by Lagrange inversion from the expansion of the negative powers of $h(w)$ at $w=\tau$.
Lagrange inversion expresses the coefficients of powers of one power series as the coefficients of another, namely:
$$
[y^n]g(y)=\frac{1}{n}[x^{n-1}]\left(\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)^n,
$$
where $f(g(y)) = y$.
How does one utilize Lagrange inversion here to expand $y(z)$ using $h(y)$?
